# Deseo usar NEXT JS, es necesario aprender antes REACT?

Tags: next.js

Puedo saltearme totalmente el aprendizaje de REACT para usar NEXT?
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Nextjs es un framework basado en React.

Comment: Procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad o basadas en opiniones: lee [answer].